# Disabling location bar updates on anchor links?

Tags: jquery-mobile

When calling changePage() with changeHash = false, the location bar does not change.
Can I have identical behavior with anchor links (e.g. `<a href="#three">Blah</a>`)? I set $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false, but the location bar is still updated.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done by setting `$.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;`

Sample code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
            $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
        });
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <a data-role="button" href="#page2">Go to page2</a>
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->

<div data-role="page" id="page2">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>Page content goes here.</p>      
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks - tried it and seems to work! Now the question is - where is this buried in the JQM docs?

Comment: Glad to be of help.I didnt get it from the docs.Got it from the JQM javascript file.

Answer (score 2):

figured I'd answer this with a nifty block of code that you can put BEFORE you load jquery mobile AFTER you load jquery, adds the extra attribute 'data-change-hash' to any link tag  so that the location does not change

```
    $('a[data-change-hash="false"]').on('click',function(e) {
        $.mobile.changePage($(this).attr('href'),{'changeHash':false});
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

will enable you to do this

```
<a href='#my-page' data-change-hash="false">Test Me!</a>
```

and your url will stay like http://example.com instead of changing to http://example.com#my-page

Comment: I agree . . . this is a nifty block of code!  Should be part of jqm, and you should get a lot more upvotes for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

try it out:  it works for me in jQM 1.4.5

```
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
```

When applied then page changes does not alter the browser's address bar anymore, in the same way when using explicit calls to:

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change","tosomewhere.html",{ changeHash: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I like Chad Brown's solution for this, I went with a much simpler and easier to grasp approach specially for people new to jquery.

so I start by creating a function script and can be placed anywhere with in your code, doesn't need to be in a specific handler or callback.

```
<script>

    function goTo(pageID,track){
         $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change','#'+pageID, {changeHash: track});
    }

</script>
```

and then in my anchor  tags I will do just call the function just like this

```
<a href="javascript:goTo('mypageID',false);">New Trip</a>
```